# How to prevent local notification duplication in ios?

Tags: ios, notifications, local, uilocalnotification

- `evenArray[]` contain a list of local notification
- I have function which create localnotification but it calls in edit and add module so it called multiple times and duplicate the local notification
- Please let me know the condition how to check notification in this array with my current notification which i will create only when it doesnt duplicate.

this is the notification which parameter i will needed to compare my notifications to this "144=mas" 144 is unique and index is also unique

```
 "<UIConcreteLocalNotification: 0x118b08c0>{fire date = Monday, September 29, 2014 at 6:12:00 PM India Standard Time, time zone = Asia/Kolkata (GMT+5:30) offset 19800, repeat interval = NSWeekCalendarUnit, repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date = Monday, September 29, 2014 at 6:12:00 PM India Standard Time, user info = {\n    144 = mas;\n    index = 63;\n    userid = \"821e25e7-d76c-4328-bbba-8e367dc70c04\";\n}}",
"<UIConcreteLocalNotification: 0x118b0cc0>{fire date = Monday, September 29, 2014 at 6:12:00 PM India Standard Time, time zone = Asia/Kolkata (GMT+5:30) offset 19800, repeat interval = NSWeekCalendarUnit, repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date = Monday, September 29, 2014 at 6:12:00 PM India Standard Time, user info = {\n    153 = mbg;\n    index = 64;\n    userid = \"821e25e7-d76c-4328-bbba-8e367dc70c04\";\n}}"
```

)

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent it by clearing previous notification using **[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)]** or **[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications]**.

You also have NSArray with scheduled notificaiton in **[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]**.

With these methods you should be able to manage your notifications.

Answer (score 1):

What i am understand after reading your question when you edit a record the same notification which already added by you in adding time added again in editing time. if it is right, you need to delete previous notification when you edit record. if you having multiple record and with respect to that record you having multiple notification you need to give some unique id with that notification so that you can easily identify which notification you need to delete.

I also faced the same issue, So i have store a unique value in `userInfo` dictionary as a integer , and whenever i adding or editing notification, first i checked it , if it is already added remove it and add another because i my case i want notification according to edited record.

the code which i was using is here, may be it will be helpful to you.

```
    -(void )scheduleNotification:(NSString *)remainderText :(BOOL )isRepeat :(NSDate *)fireDate :(NSString *)notificationId{

    NSDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dict setValue:@"NotificationID" forKeyPath:notificationId];
    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    localNotification.alertBody=@"Your Msg";
    localNotification.timeZone=[NSTimeZone localTimeZone];


    localNotification.userInfo = dict;
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;


    localNotification.fireDate=fireDate;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}

-(void) deleteNotification:(NSString *)curentNotificationId
{
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSArray *eventArray = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];


    for (int i=0; i<[eventArray count]; i++)
    {
        UILocalNotification* oneEvent = [eventArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSDictionary *userInfoCurrent = oneEvent.userInfo;
        NSString *uid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[userInfoCurrent valueForKey:@"NotificationID"]];

        if ([uid isEqualToString:curentNotificationId])
        {
            //Cancelling local notification
            [app cancelLocalNotification:oneEvent];
        }
    }

}
```

Check it.. write other things in schedule notification method which you want, and remember notificationID using which passed to scheduleNotification method should be unique

Comment: In my code when i click on single notification it cleares all from notification center. Even i have allocated uid.

Answer (score -1):

**If you want to remove specific Notification  Use below**

for notification in UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications

{

UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(notification)

}

**Or**

**If you want to remove all Notification Use below**

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications].